# Using ('s) when describing object usage

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, grammaticality

Which sentence is correct?

> We prefer Chrome because it is the most widely used browser. As of 2019, Chrome usage is 50%

Or,

> We prefer Chrome because it is the most widely used browser. Chrome's usage is 50%

Comment: It could be either. You need to provide more specific context. Are you talking about the percentage of browsers that exist or are you talking about the percentage of something that Chrome does (takes part in)?

Comment: @Jason Bassford can you check now. I added more to the sentence. I mean the percentage of browsers that exist.

Comment: It woulkd be helpful to say 50% **of what**.

Comment: 50% is the percentage of its usage, implicitly compared to other browsers.

Comment: But how is 'usage" being measured? No of calls to sampled sites in some specific period? Number of copies found installed in some survey? or what?

Comment: According to a website which I cite in the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the phrase

> As of 2019, Chrome usage is 50%

is perhaps not strictly incorrect, as it can be interpreted as a compound noun, in my opinion here a possessive form is significantly clearer and better:

> As of 2019, Chrome's usage is 50%

Better yet is to recast the sentence, as:

> - As of 2019, the usage of Chrome is 50%
> - As of 2019, the usage of the Chrome browser is 50%

The final form makes the subject maximally clear, as other things may be known as "chrome".

Furthermore, the sentence would be improved by indicating 50% of what. Of browsers installed? of browsers used recently? Or some other measure? and what is the source of this figure?

Comment: "Chrome usage" is perhaps, inelegant, but it's a common phrase.